# How can I overwrite or remove 'element.style'?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fairly new to web development and currently I am stuck on making a drop down menu transition out of sight. At the moment I have an `onclick="showMenu()` and `onclick="hideMenu()` which links to the script:

```
  function showMenu() {
    navLinks.style.right = "0";
    console.log("Show");
  }

  function hideMenu() {
    navLinks.style.right = "-200px important";
    console.log("Hide");
  }
```

The hideMenu() function does nothing because it is being overwritten im not sure how or why it is being overwritten.

[element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhKHI.png)

How can I overwrite this or disable it?

Comment: Do you call both functions on click?

Comment: Can you add the css /html (only pertinent) in your post? Are you using jquery?

Comment: Use `!important`, missing `!`

Answer (score 0):

The reason here may be you have defined two `function` for same event `onclick` which make that only one is applied which is first used .

You can use `toggle` to hide/show menu by clicking on same button , like this :

**JS**

```
function showHideMenu(){
reed1 = document.getElementById("idOfYourMenu");
cardData.classList.toggle("showHide");
}
```

**CSS**

```
{
.showHide{
right: 0px;/*If menu has right:-200px as initial value*/
}
```